# How does the Startup class come into play?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin

I've been looking at ASP.NET Web API default project which comes with ASP.NET Identity authentication and it uses Owin. I've googled about it and saw that Owin is meant to decouple the app from the server and that it's functionality is based on a `Startup` class which really does exits in the project. The class is split into two files and is like that

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}

public partial class Startup
{
    static Startup()
    {
        PublicClientId = "self";

        UserManagerFactory = () => new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>());

        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
    }

    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

    public static Func<UserManager<IdentityUser>> UserManagerFactory { get; set; }

    public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

        // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
        //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
        //    clientId: "",
        //    clientSecret: "");

        //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
        //    consumerKey: "",
        //    consumerSecret: "");

        //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
        //    appId: "",
        //    appSecret: "");

        //app.UseGoogleAuthentication();
    }
}
```

The first file, however, above the namespace has this line

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebApplication1.Startup))]
```

Now this class is used just on the auth controller, but basically it is used just to build the user manager and to get the `OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat` and `PublicClientId` info.

In that setting the class is just being used to provide those informations. So, how this class really comes into play? I'm really not understanding the relationship between Owin and this class that aparently just provides config info.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add components into the Owin application pipeline to handle HTTP requests or nothing will happen :(

Owin uses the software design principle of [Convention over configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) to assume that your project has a class named `Startup`, with a method named `Configuration`, that accepts one parameter of the type `IAppBuilder`, which will add components into the Owin application pipeline. The purpose behind this is to make things quicker and easier for you, the programmer, to set things up so you can spend more time creating your API.

If for any reason you can't follow the `Startup` class convention exactly there are other methods to point Owin to the code that adds components into the Owin application pipeline. You have identified one of those methods: the OwinStartup Attribute.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebApplication1.Startup))]
```

You can read more about what the OWIN Startup Class does and how it is detected [here](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection).